# HTTP 500 error in simple PHP web crawler

Tags: php, web-crawler

I'm trying to run a web crawler that is pointed at one url, that has no links, the code seems fine; but, I am getting an http 500 error.

All it does with the content it crawls is echo it.

Any idea why?

```
<?php
error_reporting( E_ERROR );

define( "CRAWL_LIMIT_PER_DOMAIN", 50 );

$domains = array();

$urls = array();

function crawl( $url )
{
    global $domains, $urls;
    $parse = parse_url( $url );
    $domains[ $parse['host'] ]++;
    $urls[] = $url;

    $content = file_get_contents( $url );
    if ( $content === FALSE ){
        echo "Error: No content";
        return;
}

    $content = stristr( $content, "body" );
    preg_match_all( '/http:\/\/[^ "\']+/', $content, $matches );

    // do something with content.
    echo $content;

    foreach( $matches[0] as $crawled_url ) {
        $parse = parse_url( $crawled_url );
        if ( count( $domains[ $parse['host'] ] ) < CRAWL_LIMIT_PER_DOMAIN && !in_array( $crawled_url, $urls ) ) {
            sleep( 1 );
            crawl( $crawled_url );
        }
    }
}

crawl(http://the-irf.com/hello/hello6.html);
?>
```

Comment: You're RECEIVING a 500 from something you're crawling? or this code is GENERATING a 500 on your server? If it's your server, then check the server's error logs - it'll have more details about the 500.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
crawl(http://the-irf.com/hello/hello6.html);
```

with:

```
crawl('http://the-irf.com/hello/hello6.html');
```

The URL is a text string, so it must be enclosed in quotes.



About your problem with [stristr](http://php.net/stristr):

> Returns all of haystack starting from and including the first occurrence of needle to the end.

So, your code:

```
$content = stristr( $content, "body" );
```

will return all of `$content` starting from and including the first occurence of `body`.

Comment: Thank you. It's because file_get_contents requires the URL to have quotes around it, right?